# Listing all columns in SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to list all `DISTINCT` column names for a list of tables in a Pivot format. I need the column headers to be the actual column names so that I can see which tables are missing the column.

In the example below, using the first 2 tables, the `ChnlngAssess_PTR` should have the question attempt column (Column 6) as blank.

```
table_name      RespID  LTID    UserID  ProjectID   QuestionAttempt QType   Question
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARTWBT_PTR      RespID  LTID    UserID  ProjectID   QuestionAttempt QType   Question
ChlngAssess_PTR RespID  LTID    UserID  ProjectID                   QType   Question
```

Comment: Does all of your tables have the same columns, with the exception of some tables missing some of the columns? How many tables are you trying to compare?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. You could probably use a dynamic pivot but it is not at all clear how you know what columns should be included. We need a bit more explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  There are 74 DISTINCT column names in 34 tables.  The results would show the table name in the first column and the 74 columns in the other columns.  If a table does not have the column then the value would be blank.

Comment: Have you looked as sys.columns? Is there one table that you KNOW has all the columns you are interested in? Or do you have a separate list of those columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the AdventureWorksDW2012 with what ever your DB name is and if you want to limit the tables, put a `WHERE` clause in the first select on the `t.TABLE_NAME`

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempTable

SELECT 
    t.TABLE_NAME,
    c.COLUMN_NAME
INTO #tempTable
FROM 
    AdventureWorksDW2012.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
    inner join
    AdventureWorksDW2012.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c on c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME


DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM #tempTable) AS COLUMN_NAME


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT TABLE_NAME, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #tempTable
    PIVOT(Max(COLUMN_NAME) 
          FOR COLUMN_NAME IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  I've been scratching my bald head trying to get this to work.

Comment: Glad to hear it @Bill . Be sure to accept the answer it if it is exactly what you want. Happy hunting.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all field names in all tables in your DB.

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```